# Sysprep and Capture task sequence failing using MDT 2010

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, wds, sysprep, mdt-2010

I have created a Windows Deployment Services server in Windows 2008 R2. When I originally set it up I was able to successfully use MDT 2010 to create my boot images as well as creating task sequences that would sysprep and capture, and deploy my custom `.wim` files. Everything was working perfectly.

About a month later I boot up my Windows 7 x86 image and run Windows updates to keep my image up to date. I then go and run my sysprep and capture task sequence and I get the following errors:
[image: litetouch error messages]

I searched online for the cause of this error message and it just seems to be a generic permission denied type of error message. I then decided to completely rebuild my VM image from scratch and try again. I am still getting the same error messages as before. The following is what I have tried troubleshooting this issue:

**Troubleshooting:**

- I have ensured that that UAC and the firewall is turned completely off when trying to capture the image.
- I have tried recreating the task sequence and making sure that the deployment share is updated.
- I have ensured that the local Administrator account is enabled and has the same password as specified in the task sequence.
- I have tried joining the computer to the domain and running the task sequence and I get a different error:
  [image: litetouch error messages when joined to the domain]
- I have attempted to run the script from the command prompt with "Run as Administrator" and I still receive the same errors above.
- For testing purposes I have ensured that Everyone has read/write access to my deployment share.

I have spent days on trying to resolve this to no avail. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Below is the log info from C:\Windows\Deploymentlogs\BDD.log as requested.

```
<![LOG[LTI Windows PE applied successfully]LOG]!><time="11:48:34.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTIApply" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTIApply">
<![LOG[LTIApply processing completed successfully.]LOG]!><time="11:48:34.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTIApply" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTIApply">
<![LOG[Microsoft Deployment Toolkit version: 6.0.2223.0]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[The task sequencer log is located at C:\Users\nicy\AppData\Local\Temp\SMSTSLog\SMSTS.LOG.  For task sequence failures, please consult this log.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[Processing drivers for an X86 operating system.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[TargetOS is the current SystemDrive]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[Property DriverCleanup is now = DONE]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[Compare Image processor Type with Original [X86] = [X86].]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[Prepare machine for Sysprep.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[No driver actions can be taken for OS Images installed from *.wim files.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[ZTIDrivers processing completed successfully.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="ZTIDrivers" context="" type="1" thread="" file="ZTIDrivers">
<![LOG[Command completed, return code = -2147467259]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Litetouch deployment failed, Return Code = -2147467259  0x80004005]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="3" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[For more information, consult the task sequencer log ...\SMSTS.LOG.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Property RetVal is now = -2147467259]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Unable to copy log to the network as no SLShare value was specified.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[CleanStartItems Complete]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Unregistering TSCore.dll.]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[About to run command: wscript.exe "\\server\deploymentshare$\Scripts\LTICleanup.wsf"]LOG]!><time="11:48:35.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LiteTouch" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LiteTouch">
<![LOG[Microsoft Deployment Toolkit version: 6.0.2223.0]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Removing AutoAdminLogon registry entries]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[VSSMaxSize not specified using 5% of volume.]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Logs contained 7 errors and 0 warnings.]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Stripping BDD commands from unattend.xml template.]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Modified unattend.xml saved to C:\windows\panther\unattend.xml]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Checking mapped network drive.]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[testing drive Z: mapped to \\server\deploymentshare$]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Disconnecting drive Z: mapped to \\server\deploymentshare$]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Cleaning up C:\MININT directory.]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
<![LOG[Cleaning up TOOLS, SCRIPTS, and PACKAGES directories.]LOG]!><time="11:48:36.000+000" date="07-25-2012" component="LTICleanup" context="" type="1" thread="" file="LTICleanup">
```

Comment: Do you have connectivity to the network share during capture?

Comment: Yes I do have network connectivity during the capture process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling with this for months I have finally found a solution to my problem. The following are steps I used to resolve my issue:

1. On your Windows 7 reference PC, open the registry editor.  Navigate to `HKLM\system\setup`. Look for a multi-string value called `CloneTag`. It probably will not be there.
2. Add a new `multi-string value`, name it `CloneTag`. The actual value is not important.
3. Export the `HKLM\system\setup` key and save to a `.reg` file.
4. Edit the `.reg` file, and remove all other entries except for the `CloneTag` value.
5. Run the cscript to launch the Task Sequence selector.  Select your Sysprep and Capture Task Sequence.  Enter your credentials, and go.
6. When it gets to the part where it is executing sysprep, run your `.reg` file to quickly import the `CloneTag` multi-string value.  If you see it proceed to PE, then you should be in the clear.

Answer (score 1):

There is too much in this response to put as a comment, so I have to put this as an answer even though it doesn't address the errors you are getting in your OP:
You could update your image offline using [DISM](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744256(v=ws.10).aspx) however, you would have to download all of the updates that you want to install.

Since you are using MDT, this exact process can be done by importing all of the updates as packages and MDT runs the proper DISM scripts during deployment (again, you have to download all the updates manually), or you can enable the ‘Windows Update (Pre-Application Installation)’ or ‘Windows Update (Post-Application Installation)’ item(s) that are disabled by default in the Standard Client Task Sequence template to have the system run Windows Update during deployment. If you have WSUS setup in your environment, you can get the updates from that during the deployment. [This blog post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mniehaus/archive/2011/05/16/creating-a-fully-patched-image-using-mdt-2010-lite-touch.aspx) details all 3 of these methods of maintaining an updated image.

Hope this helps,

(signature for disclosure)

David

Windows Outreach Team - IT Pro

Comment: @nic-young Sometimes, the wmpnetwk.exe process will not allow sysprep to work. Try killing the process in Task manager and then try your Sysprep and Capture TS again. If it still fails, please post your SMSTS.log file and save all the [logs from sysprep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766514(v=ws.10).aspx) (see the bottom of the article for log file locations).

Answer (score 0):

First- there is no need to boot up your image to apply windows patches, only windows patches (which is why you want your deployment image to be as thin as possible)

Second take a look at the BDD log (c:\MININT\SMSOSD\OSDLOGS\bdd.log) or (c:\windows\temp\depoymentlogs\bdd.log) that should tell you where it failed (or post it so others can look at it)

Comment: I was not aware that you could inject windows updates offline in to an image. Is there a link you could post on how to do this? Also I have added the BDD.log as requested.

Comment: The BDD log is saying to check the SMSTS log for more information, possibly there is an error in that log that gives more detail about why this failed.

Comment: as winoutreach stated, DISM is the mechanism to apply offline patches (I suggest an additional question as to how to apply them rather than try to answer that here)

Answer (score 0):

Log-in to the computer you are trying to capture the image of, access the deployment share and run the LiteTouch.vbs -  it under the folder "Scripts".